# Android Application onCreate() is called late

Tags: android, initialization, delay, launch

I have sub classed the Application class in one of my android apps where I do some application level initialization work in onCreate() method.

From the app log I can see that the actual initialization work done in the onCreate method takes only around 200 milliseconds.

But it takes around 10 - 15 seconds from when I click the app icon in launcher before the Application.onCreate() method is called. Other apps on my device launch fast enough so I don't suspect memory constraints.

Any suggestions?

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    private static String TAG = "MyApplication";

    // Class member variables

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Its taking 10-15 seconds to reach here");
        super.onCreate();

        Log.d(TAG, "Perform application specific Initialize work");
        .
        .
        // Init AsyncTasks
        .
        .
        Log.d(TAG, "Application specific Initialize completed");
    }
}
```

**Update**

I was using many SDKs like Facebook, Google Plus, LinkedIn at Application level for access from various classes and services. Although the initialization was performed using AsyncTasks, I had defined member variables for the corresponding SDK objects in the Application class. Probably some long work was performed in the constructors somewhere in the SDKs. Anyway, I am going for thorough optimization of the app including the architecture and the number of dependencies.

Also, updated all the Libraries to take care of any bugs.

I'll post the results once I complete.

Comment: Post your code here.

Comment: No but I am trying to reduce app dependencies

Comment: Can you please share the culprit. I am also facing same problem.

Comment: got any solution?